# What is wrong with "Where should this car be parked?"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

Why does Microsoft Word 2010 show an error for the following sentence?

> 1. Where should this car be parked?

Word 2010 also suggests changing the sentence to

> 2. Where this car should be parked?

Is the sentence (1) wrong? If yes, why? What about sentence (2)?

Comment: Guess what?  You write better than Microsoft.  (Sometimes you have to let common sense prevail, particularly when dealing with grammar checkers.)

Comment: Like Tim said, if you leave off the question mark, then option 2 is correct. Are you sure you had the question mark at the end when Word marked it incorrect?

Comment: @Marthaª yes I had the question mark. It is a question.

Comment: One of my kids once had a grammar test where she was given twenty sentences and was supposed to identify the grammar errors in each. For amusement, I typed this test into MS Word. It flagged many things that were correct as errors, and missed many of the real errors. It got a 60-something percent on the test. Take any message from a computer grammar checker as a suggestion, not an authoritative ruling.

Comment: ***PLEASE*** ignore Microsoft’s blather. It’s its own curse.

Comment: MS Word's grammar checker is so bad it's worse than useless.  It actively promotes bad grammar through its faults and wastes peoples time second guessing its suggestions, as your question illustrates. For another example, it flags "If I were rich" as wrong and suggests "If I _was_ rich" (or at least it used to).  I disagree with Jay about taking its messages as suggestions.  I say don't even waste time considering its suggestions because they are so bad. Just turn it off.

Comment: @ Old Pro But is it not a way to at least know that one needs to review the underlined sentence/phrase? It may encourage us to be careful even if it does not give the correct suggestion.

Comment: @OldPro  Doesn't a lot of it depend on how good your writing is. If you write well enough you'll never make the categories of errors it is able to detect reliably; and only end up seeing the false positives?  OTOH if your writing/spelling/typing is poor, most of its suggestions are either legitimate grammar problems or cases where your spelling error/typo is a real word that doesn't make sense where it occurred.

Comment: @Dan, MS's spell checker is great, and I encourage you to use it. Its grammar checker is harmful.  If you are a poor writer, you will not have the knowledge and confidence to ignore its bad advice and, as Jay pointed out, are about as likely to be misled as to be correctly corrected, which will only further confuse you while not improving your writing overall.

Comment: I agree completely with @OldPro here. The MS Word grammar checker is worse than useless. It doesn't even offer half-decent suggestions, regardless of your writing aptitude, and often gives really bad advice. Just turn it off. The spellchecker is good though.

Comment: @tchrist: Do you get a green squiggly line under "It's its" if you type that sentence in MSWord?

Comment: This is a very surprising mistake for MS Word to make, and I suspect that Stat-R is not telling us the whole story. See the first comment to Lynn's answer. Stat-R, are you really giving us the whole sentence? Or was it something like "I don't know where should this car be parked"?

Comment: @TonyK. I guess "I do not know" is optional in the sentence I wrote.

Comment: No! That's the whole point. So I was right, was I?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When used as a stand-alone sentence, you're right:

> 1) Where should this car be parked? **<-- correct**
>
> 2) Where this car should be parked?

Now... if it's part of a larger sentence it's different:

> 1) Do you know where should this car be parked?
>
> 2) Do you know where this car should be parked?  **<-- correct**

I would speculate that either there was some other typo that made MS Word think you were in the second scenario, or it was just a flat-out bug in the grammar checker.

Comment: @ Lynn is it possible to explain how "Do you know where should this car be parked?" is incorrect? Sorry for the novice clarification.

Comment: "Where this car should be parked" is a fact, so the sentence structure is:  "Do you know (a fact)?"    "Where should this be parked?" is a question.  That would make the question:  "Do you know (a question)?"   That usage may not be technically incorrect, but it sure sounds strange.

Comment: It could also be that Stat-R is using a different version of Word, that has an older (or newer) Grammar Checker.

Comment: @aslum - Yeah actually my version parsed it as an error too, it just took it a minute so I didn't notice right away.  I updated my response.

Comment: It's not a typo: Microsoft Word thinks you're in the second scenario even though you're not. You can ask it for clarification, and it says ***"If your sentence includes a statement about a question rather than a direct question, the subject should come before the verb.
Instead of: He asked the bus driver when would the next bus come.
Consider: He asked the bus driver when the next bus would come."*** Its grammar checker is really poor.

Answer (score 9):

1. is right; 2. is wrong.  The grammar checker probably got confused by the fact that if the question mark were omitted, it would be the other way round.

It may be possible to devise a computerised grammar for English that makes fewer mistakes than a schoolchild (always a good discussion topic in the bar), but Microsoft Word doesn't have one.