# Is "They won't tell me where is the office" correct?

Tags: word-usage

Which sentence is correct?

> 1. They won't tell me where is the office.
> 2. They won't tell me where the office is.

Comment: Your title asks one question and your text asks a different question. They have opposite answers, and if you can't tell the difference between one question and another, it's unlikely we can offer you any help.

Comment: related (possible dupe) to the edited question: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68737/8019

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/608581/2085).

Answer (score 1):

The difference is between

> a question in direct reported speech, or **direct question**
>
> *He asked: "Where is the station?"*
>
> *He asked: "What are you doing this evening?"*

and

> a question in indirect reported speech, or **indirect question**
>
> *He asked where the station was/is* (if the situation of the station has not changed).
>
> *He asked what I was doing that evening.*

The word order in an indirect question is the word order of a declarative sentence, not of an interrogative one, that is:

> Subject | (Auxiliary) | Verb | Object

There is no Auxiliary-Subject or Verb-Subject inversion as is the case in an interrogative sentence.

And there is not a question mark either.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the office? They won't tell me where the office is.

Answer (score 0):

*They won't tell me where the office is* is correct.

The problem with the first sentence is that using *where* + *is* is creating an [interrogative mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative), when the beginning of the sentence suggests an [indicative mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood#Indicative).

The interrogative mood is commonly conveyed by inverting the subject-verb order. <sup>[[Source]](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/grammar_moods.html)[[Author]](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/cv.html)</sup> The subject is *the office* and *is* is the verb, in the sentences you mentioned in the body of your question.