# embedded interrogative Clause when quoting

Tags: grammar

Today I heard someone saying "...people ask me how can I ...", I know it's wrong, but then again, what if she was quoting?

So the question is:
Can you change an embedded interrogative clause to a quote when you speak?

E.g. "He asked me how he can get there?"
       "He asked me "how can I get there?""

I personally don't do that cause it might get confusing, (it's okay when you are writing, right?) but if you have to, can you?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I see I have to consider this as a duplicate of ["I'm not sure what the right way is"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/im-not-sure-what-the-right-way-is) but 583's answer at [Is 'They won't tell me where is the office' correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152849/is-they-wont-tell-me-where-is-the-office-correct/152890#152890), closed as a duplicate, is closer.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/608581/2085).

Answer (score 0):

Direct speech:

Question: "How **can** I get there?"

Reported speech: He asked me how he **could get** there.

Question: "What **is** your name?"

Reported speech: She asked me what my name **was**.

With the verb to be, take care to put the verb at the end.

Question: "When **can you come**?"

Reported Speech: She asked me when I **could come**.

Question: "**When **did they leave****?"

Reported Speech: He asked me when **they left**.

All direct speech can be converted to indirect speech. It can become slightly complicated but I have given a few more examples.

The problem is that you hear a lot of people just transposing the speech and not actually reporting it:

Question: "When **are you expecting** an answer"? [question form]

**Incorrect**: "They asked me **when are you expecting** an answer".

Correct: "They asked me **when you are expecting** an answer".

The verb must be put in some past tense.

Basically reported speech calls for questions to return to a statement form, which means you have to make sure the verbs are not inverted.