# "Is there" or "there is"?

Tags: word-order, subject-verb-inversion

Do I need to use "is there" or "there is" in the following sentence?

> It is natural to ask under which conditions is there a subtype
>   relation between two given arrow types.

If I change "is" to "be" the order is clearly "there be".

Comment: I would only use the order *...is there...* if it involved direct speech. In this kind of reported speech, it should be *...there is***. Similarly if you use *...be there/there be...*

Comment: Related: [How is “Can anyone tell me how can I solve this” wrong?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161001)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/608581/2085).

Answer (score 4):

The correct order in the sentence is “there is”.

The inversion of the subject-verb word order mainly occurs in questions. When the interrogative clause is a question on its own, the correct order is “Is there”:

> Under which conditions is there a subtype relation between two given arrow types?

When cited as a direct quotation, that inversion order remains:

> It is natural to ask: “Under which conditions is there a subtype relation between two given arrow types?”

But when used as a subordinate interrogative clause, the normal subject-verb word order is used:

> It is natural to ask under which conditions there is a subtype relation between two given arrow types.

<sub>Edit: it’s a subordinate interrogative clause, not a relative clause. Hat tip: BillJ in comment below.</sub>

Comment: Hmm, those suggestions seem to change the meaning, at least in my mind.  I might try the following, but wonder whether it becomes more obscure or less.

One might ask what conditions are necessary and sufficient that there be a subtype relation between two arrow types.

Comment: It's not a relative clause. "Under which conditions there is a subtype relation between two given arrow types" is a 'subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question).

Answer (score 2):

"Is there" is used in **argumentative** sentences.

> Is there someone over the hill?

"There is" is used in **affirmative** sentences.

> There is a cow over the hill.

---

So it would be more common to write your phrase like this:

> It is natural to ask under which conditions there is a subtype relation between two given arrow types.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage!  You might want to take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help), especially the section on [writing a good answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).  Can you explain _why_, in this situation, it would be written that way?  Can you provide some links to supporting evidence?

Comment: Hello, Roger! Thanks for the tip. I will have a look at those links to elaborate better my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The latter is technically correct. The former leans towards colloquial. Both are awkward. Consider changing it to:

> It would be logical to ask under which conditions a subtype relation
>   would exist [or: emerge; or: become obvious; or: manifest itself]
>   between two given arrow types.

Or:

> It would only be logical to ask under which conditions a subtype
>   relation between two given arrow types would become evident.

Or:

> One would be naturally inclined to ask at that point under which
>   conditions a subtype relation between two given arrow types would
>   manifest itself.

Answer (score 0):

> *It is natural to ask* [*under which conditions is there* / *there is a*
>   *subtype relation between two given arrow types*].

The bracketed constituent is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question). Unlike main clause interrogatives, there is normally no inversion, so “there is” is the correct version.

The meaning can be glossed as:

"It is natural to ask the answer to the question 'Under which conditions is there a subtype relation between two given arrow types?'"